# Heroku Scheduler "Next Due" time keeps increasing

Tags: heroku, scheduler

I'm working on using Heroku's Scheduler add-on (node-cron doesn't seem to be working for me).  I installed the add-on and added a new job (set its frequency to every 10 minutes).  However, the job never seems to execute.  Upon further inspection, I found that the "next due" time keeps increasing.

In other words, let's say the current time is 1:00.  The next due time should be (and is) 1:10.  5 minutes later, the current time is 1:05.  Even though the next due time should still be 1:10, it changes to 1:15 (basically always being 10 minutes ahead of current time).  How do I fix this?

Comment: I know this issue is over two years old, but I'm having the exact same issue and there are no answers here. Did you ever get this resolved?